# Build error when attempting to run a netbeans project shared using subversion

Tags: java, netbeans, build, glassfish, deployment

I work with a team on a java web application project. I created the project and committed it on an svn server that we use to share our code. The project runs fine on my computer but every other team member gets the error message below every time they try to run the project. I can't find anything online that has been helpful. Any ideas that might lead to finding what is going will be helpful. Thank you

> Starting GlassFish Server 3 1
>   GlassFish Server 3 1 is running.
>   In-place deployment at C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Administrator\My
>   Documents\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio\build\web
>   deploy?path=C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Administrator\My
>   Documents\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio\build\web&name=Portfolio&force=true
>   failed on GlassFish Server 3 1
>   C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Administrator\My
>   Documents\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: The
>   module has not been deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Since i am also using jpa for database access the reference to the data source in the persistence unit did not exist in my team members server instances. So I had them create a data source using the same name i used and it worked. However i don't know what is the best way to do this, I had them create a dummy web application in netbeans and then use the Entity Classes From Database wizard to generate the entity which forces them to create a datasource and I had them use the same datasource name I reference in the project. If they did this and ran the project it would automatically be added in their glassfish instance and hence they can now run the shared project. I would be glad to hear alternatives to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the files to see if you have an absolute reference with the full path to the above file instead of a relative one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I found out that the issue was since i am also using jpa for database access the reference to the data source in the persistence unit did not exist in my team members server instances.